# Kubernetes environment installation with Ansible

Tags: ansible, kubernetes

I write a ansible playbook for Kubernetes environment (timedata, swap, modules, containerd, kubeadm, kubelet, kubectl, vs). When I run the playbook, all operations in it are successful. But when I control the on vm, kubelet is not working

This is my playbook

```
- name: K8S Worker Deploybook
  hosts:
  - worker
  - master
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    - name: k8s_version
      prompt: "Kubernetes version"
      default: latest
      private: no

  tasks:    
    # Swap yapılandırması
    - name: Sistem saat yapılandırması
      shell:
        cmd: hwclock --hctosys
    - name: Swap alanlarının kapatılması
      shell:
        cmd: swapoff -a
    - name: /etc/fstab içerisindeki swap tanımlarının önüne diyez ekler
      shell:
        cmd: sed -i 's/^\(.*swap\)/#\1/g' /etc/fstab

    # Tarih saat ayarları
    - name: Install chrony download with apt
      apt: 
        name: chrony
        state: present
    - name: Chrony configuration on debian based
      blockinfile:
        path: /etc/chrony/chrony.conf
        block: |
          server 0.tr.pool.ntp.org
          server 1.tr.pool.ntp.org
          server 2.tr.pool.ntp.org
          server 3.tr.pool.ntp.org
        state: present
    - name: Service
      service:
        name: chronyd
        state: restarted
        enabled: yes
    - name: Timezone configuration
      timezone:
        name: Europe/Istanbul

    # Tüm paketlerin güncellenmesi
    - name: Sistemdeki tüm paketlerin güncellenmesi
      apt:
        name: "*"
        state: latest
        update_cache: yes

    # Modül tanımlarının yapılması
    - name: overlay modülünün aktif edilmesi
      shell:
        cmd: modprobe overlay
    - name: br_netfilter modülünün aktifleştirilmesi    
      shell:
        cmd: modprobe br_netfilter
    - name: Modüllerin konfigürasyon dosyasına işlenmesi
      blockinfile:
        path: /etc/modules-load.d/k8s.conf
        block: |
          overlay
          br_netfilter
        state: present
        create: yes
    - name: Network kurallarının tanımlanması
      blockinfile:
        path: /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
        block: |
          net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables  = 1
          net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
          net.ipv4.ip_forward                 = 1
        state: present
        create: yes
    - name: Yapılan ayarların sisteme uygulanması
      shell:
        cmd: sysctl --system

    # Containerd kurulumnları
    - name: Containerd paket deposunun gpg keylerinin eklenmesi 
      shell:
        cmd: curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker.gpg
    - name: Containerd paket depolarının eklenmesi
      shell:
        cmd: echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list 
    - name: Paket depolarının güncellenmesi
      apt:
        update_cache: yes
    - name: Containerd kurulması
      apt:
        name: containerd.io
        state: latest
    - name: Sistemdeki deamonların yeniden başlatılması
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        daemon_reload: true
    - name: Containerd servisini başlat ve yeniden başlatma sonrasında başlayacak şekilde konumlandır
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        name: containerd
        state: started
        enabled: true
    - name: Containerd konfigürasyon dizininin oluşturulması
      file:
        path: /etc/containerd
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: "0755"
        state: directory
    - name: Containerd default konfigürasyonun dosyaya yazılması
      shell: 
        cmd: containerd config default | tee /etc/containerd/config.toml
    - name: 
      shell: 
        cmd: sed -i 's/            SystemdCgroup = false/            SystemdCgroup = true/' /etc/containerd/config.toml
    - name: Containerd servisinin yeniden başlatılması
      service:
        name: containerd
        state: restarted

    # Kubernetes bileşenlerinin kurulması
    - name: APT Update
      apt:
        update_cache: yes
    - name: Pre-required packages
      apt:
        pkg:
        - apt-transport-https
        - ca-certificates
        - curl
    - name: Kubernets paket deposunun gpg keylerinin eklenmesi 
      shell:
        cmd: curl -fsSL https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg
    - name: Kubernetes paket depolarının eklenmesi
      shell:
        cmd: echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
    - name: APT Update
      apt:
        update_cache: yes
    - name: Install kubelet
      apt:
        name: kubelet
        state: "{{k8s_version}}"
    - name: Install kubeadm
      apt:
        name: kubeadm
        state: "{{k8s_version}}"
    - name: Install kubectl
      apt:
        name: kubectl
        state: "{{k8s_version}}"
    - name: Hold kubelet
      dpkg_selections:
        name: kubelet
        selection: hold
    - name: Hold kubeadm
      dpkg_selections:
        name: kubeadm
        selection: hold
    - name: Hold kubectl
      dpkg_selections:
        name: kubectl
        selection: hold
    - name: Remove dependencies that are no longer required
      apt:
        autoremove: yes
    - name: Remove useless packages from the cache
      apt:
        autoclean: yes
```

I see this error on journalctl

```
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.780055   62503 server.go:467] "Kubelet version" kubeletVersion="v1.28.2"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.780142   62503 server.go:469] "Golang settings" GOGC="" GOMAXPROCS="" GOTRACEBACK=""
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.780560   62503 server.go:630] "Standalone mode, no API client"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.794365   62503 server.go:518] "No api server defined - no events will be sent to API server"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.794385   62503 server.go:725] "--cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not specified.  defaulting to /"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.794549   62503 container_manager_linux.go:265] "Container manager verified user specified cgroup-root exists" cgroupRoot=[]
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.794703   62503 container_manager_linux.go:270] "Creating Container Manager object based on Node Config" nodeConfig={"RuntimeCgroupsName":"","SystemCgroupsName":"","KubeletCgroupsName":"","KubeletOOMScoreAdj":-999,"ContainerRuntime":"","CgroupsPerQOS":true,"CgroupRoot":"/","CgroupDriver":"cgroupfs","KubeletRootDir":"/var/lib/kubelet","ProtectKernelDefaults":false,"KubeReservedCgroupName":"","SystemReservedCgroupName":"","ReservedSystemCPUs":{},"EnforceNodeAllocatable":{"pods":{}},"KubeReserved":null,"SystemReserved":null,"HardEvictionThresholds":[],"QOSReserved":{},"CPUManagerPolicy":"none","CPUManagerPolicyOptions":null,"TopologyManagerScope":"container","CPUManagerReconcilePeriod":10000000000,"ExperimentalMemoryManagerPolicy":"None","ExperimentalMemoryManagerReservedMemory":null,"PodPidsLimit":-1,"EnforceCPULimits":true,"CPUCFSQuotaPeriod":100000000,"TopologyManagerPolicy":"none","TopologyManagerPolicyOptions":null}
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.794723   62503 topology_manager.go:138] "Creating topology manager with none policy"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.794731   62503 container_manager_linux.go:301] "Creating device plugin manager"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.794800   62503 state_mem.go:36] "Initialized new in-memory state store"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.794840   62503 kubelet.go:399] "Kubelet is running in standalone mode, will skip API server sync"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.795167   62503 kuberuntime_manager.go:257] "Container runtime initialized" containerRuntime="containerd" version="1.6.24" apiVersion="v1"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.795437   62503 volume_host.go:74] "KubeClient is nil. Skip initialization of CSIDriverLister"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: W1022 20:12:58.795559   62503 probe.go:268] Flexvolume plugin directory at /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/ does not exist. Recreating.
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: W1022 20:12:58.795885   62503 csi_plugin.go:189] kubernetes.io/csi: kubeclient not set, assuming standalone kubelet
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: W1022 20:12:58.795998   62503 csi_plugin.go:266] Skipping CSINode initialization, kubelet running in standalone mode
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.796279   62503 server.go:1232] "Started kubelet"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.796422   62503 server.go:162] "Starting to listen" address="0.0.0.0" port=10250
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.796435   62503 kubelet.go:1579] "No API server defined - no node status update will be sent"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.796455   62503 server.go:194] "Starting to listen read-only" address="0.0.0.0" port=10255
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.797766   62503 fs_resource_analyzer.go:67] "Starting FS ResourceAnalyzer"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.796499   62503 ratelimit.go:65] "Setting rate limiting for podresources endpoint" qps=100 burstTokens=10
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.798430   62503 server.go:233] "Starting to serve the podresources API" endpoint="unix:/var/lib/kubelet/pod-resources/kubelet.sock"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: E1022 20:12:58.796812   62503 cri_stats_provider.go:448] "Failed to get the info of the filesystem with mountpoint" err="unable to find data in memory cache" mountpoint="/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: E1022 20:12:58.798457   62503 kubelet.go:1431] "Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet" err="invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.798432   62503 server.go:462] "Adding debug handlers to kubelet server"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.799218   62503 volume_manager.go:291] "Starting Kubelet Volume Manager"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.799280   62503 desired_state_of_world_populator.go:151] "Desired state populator starts to run"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.799325   62503 reconciler_new.go:29] "Reconciler: start to sync state"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.821444   62503 cpu_manager.go:214] "Starting CPU manager" policy="none"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.821460   62503 cpu_manager.go:215] "Reconciling" reconcilePeriod="10s"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.821471   62503 state_mem.go:36] "Initialized new in-memory state store"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.847618   62503 policy_none.go:49] "None policy: Start"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.848345   62503 memory_manager.go:169] "Starting memorymanager" policy="None"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.848373   62503 state_mem.go:35] "Initializing new in-memory state store"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.872491   62503 manager.go:471] "Failed to read data from checkpoint" checkpoint="kubelet_internal_checkpoint" err="checkpoint is not found"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.872776   62503 plugin_manager.go:118] "Starting Kubelet Plugin Manager"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.899854   62503 desired_state_of_world_populator.go:159] "Finished populating initial desired state of world"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.910726   62503 kubelet_network_linux.go:50] "Initialized iptables rules." protocol="IPv4"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.913220   62503 kubelet_network_linux.go:50] "Initialized iptables rules." protocol="IPv6"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.913254   62503 status_manager.go:213] "Kubernetes client is nil, not starting status manager"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: I1022 20:12:58.913264   62503 kubelet.go:2303] "Starting kubelet main sync loop"
Oct 22 20:12:58 kube01 kubelet[62503]: E1022 20:12:58.913299   62503 kubelet.go:2327] "Skipping pod synchronization" err="PLEG is not healthy: pleg has yet to be successful"
Oct 22 20:13:08 kube01 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Current command vanished from the unit file, execution of the command list won't be resumed.
Oct 22 20:13:08 kube01 systemd[1]: Stopping kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent...
Oct 22 20:13:08 kube01 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 22 20:13:08 kube01 systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Oct 22 20:13:08 kube01 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Oct 22 20:13:08 kube01 kubelet[62751]: E1022 20:13:08.519080   62751 run.go:74] "command failed" err="failed to load kubelet config file, path: /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error: failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file \"/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml\", error: open /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory"
Oct 22 20:13:08 kube01 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 22 20:13:08 kube01 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 22 20:13:18 kube01 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Oct 22 20:13:18 kube01 systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Oct 22 20:13:18 kube01 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Oct 22 20:13:18 kube01 kubelet[62995]: E1022 20:13:18.805505   62995 run.go:74] "command failed" err="failed to load kubelet config file, path: /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error: failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file \"/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml\", error: open /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory"
Oct 22 20:13:18 kube01 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 22 20:13:18 kube01 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 22 20:13:28 kube01 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Oct 22 20:13:28 kube01 systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
```

I check /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml file but there is no. When I write a line by line in playbook it's worked but when playbook installed, kubelet not working.
Why might this be happening?
Do you any suggest?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing (missing `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` preventing the `kubelet` service from starting). I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 using Ansible also.

Comment: @AdrianTorrie thank for try. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 too. Can you try playbook jobs step by step? I think kubelet will work this way but I can't figure how